# given view is docked in another place via avalondock then it is reinitialized

Tags: c#, avalondock

I have following issue.
I use DockingManager like this:

```
<xcad:DockingManager Name="DockingManager" AnchorablesSource="{Binding FooterTools}" DocumentsSource="{Binding MainWindowTools}"
                    ActiveContent="{Binding ActiveDocument, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ActiveDocumentConverter}}"
                    avBehav:AvalonDockLayoutSerializer.LoadLayoutCommand="{Binding AdLayout.LoadLayoutCommand}"
                    avBehav:AvalonDockLayoutSerializer.SaveLayoutCommand="{Binding AdLayout.SaveLayoutCommand}">
```

I observed that when I got one of anchorableSource docked in the buttom of my application and then I when dock it out then it keeps it data.

Then when I dock it to the tabbed place (I suppose it is where those items of DocumentSourcedStyle are located ) then my control is re-initialized (it constructor is invoked ) therefore it losts some data which were depicted previously.

Did sb met such issue?

Comment: I'm seeing something similar.  Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Yes, I bought WPF  Extended Toolkit Plus - with plus version above problem disappeared. Maybe  community edition will have this issue solved in future. Who knows.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I ended up caching the view with Caliburn Micro.